# CRZ and CRY Gates

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, pauli-gates

I am trying to understand the function of the $CR_z$ and $CR_y$ gates.

Why are these gates used in practice? What advantage is gained by rotating a qubit around the $y$- or $z$-axis?

For example, this code from the Qiskit tutorial's Tic-Tac-Toe game ([original source](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/4e743e265bdf78ef28bd7e179fe7bde8cf67a385/community/games/game_engines/composite_gates.py#L57)) which defines the cnx gate:

```
def cnx(qc, *qubits):
  if len(qubits) >= 3:
    last = qubits[-1]
    #What is the goal of the next two lines?
    qc.crz(np.pi/2, qubits[-2], qubits[-1])
    qc.cry(np.pi/2, 0, 0, qubits[-2],qubits[-1])
    
    #Is this a recursive call to cnx ?
    cnx(qc,*qubits[:-2],qubits[-1])
    
    #why is there another flip?
    qc.cry(-np.pi/2, 0, 0, qubits[-2], qubits[-1])
    
    #what about this line ?
    cnx(qc,*qubits[:-2],qubits[-1])
    
    #what about this line too?
    qc.crz(-np.pi/2,qubits[-2],qubits[-1])
```

Please explain the inline questions in the context of the initial question.

Thanks!

Comment: Controlled rotations of a qubit around axes are workhorses in quantum algorithms; for example, consider the controlled rotation of the marked state in Grover's algorithm.  Unlike, say, the $\mathsf{CNOT}$ or $\mathsf{CSWAP}$ gates, there is no classical analog of a controlled rotation.  Can you provide more clarity in what you know and what you are looking to learn?  Otherwise it's a little broad - like asking what the purpose of a $\mathsf{NAND}$ gate is in classical computing.

Comment: What i know is that it performs a certain angle flip of the target Qubit on the Bloch sphere following the Z -axis for the CRZ and Y - axis for the CRY if the control bit is at state 1. Now why we want to do this, in the first place ? what is it useful in, a flip ? and how the target qubit will look like (e.g an example) at the end ? how could CRZ be more useful in some calculations ? thx

Comment: It seems like you are having specific questions about a snippet of code in Qiskit, and not so much about how controlled Pauli operations are used.  It's hard to answer such "moving-target" questions and I don't know how to help further.  Maybe someone else can; however, in the future refrain from changing the context of a question and asking [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) questions.

Comment: Yes it was a double phased question but i commented on your previous answer with an additional question about what your wrote !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantum algorithms provide a computational speedup by orchestrating constructive *and* destructive interference of the amplitudes.  It is as if there must be a 8minus sign* somewhere in the matrices - otherwise we merely work in the classical world, and would not see a computational speedup.

Let's consider the following gates as controlled Pauli matrices:
\begin{align}
  CR_x&=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0&0&0\\
      0&1&0&0\\
      0&0&0&1\\
      0&0&1&0
    \end{pmatrix} \\
\\
  CR_y&=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0&0&0\\
      0&1&0&0\\
      0&0&0&-i\\
      0&0&i&0
    \end{pmatrix} \\\
\\
 CR_z&=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0&0&0\\
      0&1&0&0\\
      0&0&1&0\\
      0&0&0&-1
    \end{pmatrix} \,.
\end{align}

As can be seen, $CR_x$ does not have a minus sign - nothing gets inverted.  $CR_x$ corresponds to the $\mathsf{CNOT}$ gate; operating only with $\mathsf{CNOT}$ gates does not provide any *quantum* speedup - $\mathsf{CNOT}$ gates can be implemented classically.

Not so, however, with $CR_y$ and $CR_z$.  For example, $CR_z$ can be used to invert the probability amplitude of the marked states in Grover's algorithm.  The marked states, being inverted, will *destructively* interfere with the unmarked states during the diffusion operation.

---

As an example, consider qubits $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$.  The *target* qubit is $1$ only when the *control* qubit is $1$.

We have:

$$CR_x|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|10\rangle)$$
$$CR_y|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle-i|10\rangle)$$
$$CR_z|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|(|00\rangle-|11\rangle)$$

When the *control* qubit is $1$, the *target* qubit may have a phase of $-1$ or $-i$.

Comment: Algorithmically speaking, how is it useful the CRx CRy CRz ? in initializing any state qubit for another operation maybe etc...

Comment: I edited my question pls check it

Comment: In the last CRz expression you mean a state of \alpha |00>-|10> right ?

Comment: I could have gotten it wrong but why do you think it's $|00\rangle-|10\rangle$?  It's all $1$'s and $-1$'s on the diagonal - that means it doesn't change states on the diagonal, only phases.

Comment: Well because it's a 1 as control bit in the |10⟩ component

Comment: The $4\times 4$ matrix is read $00,01,10,11$ in both the column and row direction.  The state $|11\rangle$ corresponds to the bottom row and the far-right column.  Reading over to the column we find that it $CR_z$ maps this to $-|11\rangle$.